# Css navbar center issue

Tags: html, css

I want to center the navbar horizontally and vertically. The whole ul is supposed to be horizontally centered in the outer div, and the li text is supposed to be vertically centered. Feels like i've tried everything.

This is my html

```
 <section class="navigation" ng-controller="NavController">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <nav>
                <ul class="nav-list" ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">{{navitem.title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my css

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



.navigation {
 width: 100%;
 height: 7%;
 background: #262626;
 color: white;
} 
.navigation a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 300; 
}  
.navigation a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

.nav-container {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 height: 100%; 
 }
.nav-dropdown {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 }
 nav {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: .9em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 height: 100%; 
 }
 nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 100%; 
 display: inline-block; 
 }
 nav ul li {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; 
 }
 nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 color: #a9a9a9;
 padding: 0 20px;
 background: #262626;
 height: 100%; 
 }
 nav ul li a:hover,
 nav ul li a:focus,
 nav ul li a:active {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 }
 nav ul li > a:hover {
  background: #519ae3;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 nav ul li > a:not(:only-child):after {
 padding-left: 4px;
 content: ' ▾';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To center a float positioned on the right you'll want to counter that by setting the left margin edge to -50%.

```
left: -50%;
```

Here is where it would go in your existing code:

```
nav {
  float: right;
  left: -50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is your new full HTML and CSS. [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNPLVB)

HTML

```
<section class="navigation" ng-controller="NavController">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list" ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">{{navitem.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background: #262626;
  color: white;
}

.navigation a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

nav {
  float: right;
  left: -50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #262626;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus,
nav ul li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li > a:hover {
  background: #519ae3;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li > a:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't seem to work though. As I add more links it doesn't remain centered

Comment: If you add more links to the top just lower the left position percentage. If you update your example I can modify it to show you.

Comment: I see, the problem is that I want the website to be dynamic so it will center automatically no matter how many links you add. The best thing would be to use something similar to margin: auto. But I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your issue and you can see it HERE in snippet below.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background: #262626;
  color: white;
}

.navigation a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #262626;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus,
nav ul li a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li > a:hover {
  background: #519ae3;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li > a:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
```

```html
<section class="navigation" ng-controller="NavController">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list" ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">{{navitem.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

**NOTE:** When you want to put some items center in a container one of the most common ways is to set   `text-align:center` to container and change display of its child (items you wanna be center in a row) to   `display:inline-block`